# Is git merge smart idea in this case?

Tags: git, react-native

I have three branches (master, development and android-version).

We are working on react-native app and we have first created IOS version which is in `development branch`.

Then a few months ago we started to work on android version and I have created new branch with `git checkout -b android-version`, and thus, all files from `development branch` are copied to `android-version branch`. I have modified files on android-version branch to work on android and I have pushed it to `android-version branch`. But I didn't merge it with development branch. That was 2 months ago.

In the last two months my colleague has worked on IOS version, thus on `development` branch. Now I need to get those changes to `android-version` branch and modify them to work on android. The problem is that I have deleted a few components on `android-version branch`, and I do not want to pull them if I merge it with development branch.

Is `git merge development` smart idea?

I guess that I would get all those deleted components from `development branch` if I do merge?

Comment: If you merge changes in from the development branch into the android-version branch, and the development branch has modified some files you have deleted you will get a merge conflict. Simply resolve this by taking the deleted file (which means you will still have deleted it on your branch) and you should be OK.

Comment: You should, however, try to merge in changes from the development branch on a regular basis, so that you don't get big scary merge conflicts every two months but instead get small nice merge conflicts several times a week.

Comment: Either way, make a clone of your repository and experiment, as long as you don't push you can try everything every which way without being afraid of messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

**Merge might not be the best tool, try rebase**

If there were significant changes on the `development` branch that may need some fixes of your existing updates in `android-version` and you would like to sync android and iOS development some day, you should linearize your history, provide fixup commits to your existing work, review it and then push.

I imagine the situation is like following:

```
M - I1 - I2 <development)
 \
  \ A1 - A2 - A3 <android-version)
```

where `I` commits are for iOS and `A` for android. Herein proposed approach (`git checkout android-version; git rebase development`) will result (after solving possible collisions) in:

```
M - I1 - I2 - A1 - A2 - A3 <android-version)
          <development)
```

And now you can review your ideas, fix possible problems, etc.

After you decide that the android version does not break nothing in iOS and whole `development` can be updated, no nasty merge commits will emerge, because it will be a nice fast-forward merge.